# Browsable-intent stopped working

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-build

I try to write a browsable intent for my app that acts when a specific url is called:

```
 <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="add" >
        <!-- registers to receive SEND and VIEW intents from other apps -->
        <activity android:name="com.myAppName" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="example.com"
                       />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="www.example.com"
                       />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </gap:config-file>
```

That DID work (kind of). When entering the Url, I received a popup asking me if the browser or my app should open that url.

When selecting my app, it immediately crashed. But that is NOT the problem I need to be solved. The problem is, that after a few times, my device stopped asking me which app should open that url. It seems like there is something like a "fallback" preventing using that url after a few crashes?

I tried to reinstall my apk and restart the device. I also cleared my apps cache.

Any chance to make this work again?

Answer (score 0):

@Ole,
from your post, it appears you want to read a particular URL. As such, you've likely hit several common road blocks. Since you did not state if you are using the CLI or the cloud Build services, this information is generic.

The best place to start is:
*Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap*
https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md
You will want to read #6, #7, & #10.

You most likely need to implement the *white-list* plugin (#10), which allows you to use any URL, or a predefined set of URLS.

You will also want to start using *versions* with your code and plugins (#6 & #7). If you do not use versions when defining your program (whether CLI or Build - via config.xml), then you will get the latest code and you will constantly be dealing with the cutting edge. This means your code will work most of the times, and sometimes not at all, and sometimes it will be good one day and not work the next, and then work again. Use versions where appropriate.

Best of Luck
Jesse

Comment: Just as an addition. I tagged with phonegap-build. So I use the build services. Nonetheless, your answer is helpful. I will crawl through the links. Thx